# Manage pods based on scheme in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cocoapods

How can we manage pods based on my scheme. Suppose I want to use a pod in UAT/Debug scheme not in Prod scheme. How we can achieve that. I did quite a lot searching but didn't get any working solution.

Answer (score 3):

`Cocoapods` doesn't support for scheme, but you can work around this by using the configuration way.

1. Create a new `Configuration` (for example, named it `UATDebug`)
2. Edit your `UAT/Debug` scheme, in the edit scheme menu, change the `Build Configuration` to your `UATDebug`
3. In your `Podfile`, specific your configuration for pod, like the example that wrote in [Cocoapod docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod) (Build configurations)

> pod 'PonyDebugger', :configuration => 'Debug'